# Script to recognize file name up to "-" symbol and create folder with same name move all files into that folder

Tags: terminal.app, files-folders

I have this

```
/Folder1/108462-2.jpg
/Folder1/108462-3.jpg
/Folder1/BSR2333-1.jpg
/Folder1/BSR2333-2.jpg
/Folder1/DKS23108554-1.jpg
/Folder1/DKS23108554-2.jpg
```

I would like to have this:

```
/108462/108462-2.jpg
/108462/108462-3.jpg
/BSR2333/BSR2333-1.jpg
/BSR2333/BSR2333-2.jpg
/DKS23108554/DKS23108554-1.jpg
/DKS23108554/DKS23108554-2.jpg
```

I have seen this;

```
do if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then mkdir "${file:0:9}" mv "$file" "${file:0:9}"; fi; done
```

but does not quite do it...

But how to fix to use the whole name up to "-" to create folder and put files into that folder. Thank in advance, very new to mac terminal

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description you want to change the leading `/Folder1` to be the name of the file in the folder up to the `-` in the file's name.

This is a primitive example with [meaningful variable names](https://archive.org/details/professionalsoft0000ledg/page/n15/mode/2up?q=%22the%20naming%20thicket%22) for readable code.

```
#! /bin/bash

pathname=/Folder1/108462-2.jpg
newfolder="$(dirname "$pathname")"
newfolder="${newfolder/-.*$//}"
filenamepartofpathname="$(basename $pathname)"
newpathname="$newfolder/$filenamepartofpathname"
echo "$newpathname"
```

[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) produces no output:

```
$ shellcheck primitive-example.sh
(no output)
```

```
$ ./primitive-example.sh
/108462/108462-2.jpg
```

Note that if the file has more than one `-` you might need to adjust the primitive example.

You can also try "code golfing" https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ to get help with making it less primitive but less readable.